# Magic-8-ball? in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Just like the Magic-8-ball game does, I am trying to build a model that can answer different questions in the order of:

- "It is certain"
- "Outlook good"
- "Ask again later"
- "Outlook not so good".

And produces "you did not ask a question, try again" if the question is empty, denoted by (no-answer)

I wrote down the code for this question but the empty case is not working.

That is, `(magic-8-ball "")` should produce "you did not ask a question, try again".

```
;; 8-ball-answers: (listof string)

(define 8-ball-answers (list "It is certain" "Outlook good" "Ask again later" "Outlook not so good"))

;; no-answer: string
;; Purpose: correct form of string to produce when magic-8-ball consumes empty string

(define no-answer "you did not ask a question, try again")

;;magic-8-ball: string -> string
;;Purpose: consumes a string and produces a string
;;Effects: modifies (8-ball-answers). If the string is empty, produces
;;         "you did not ask a question, try again". Otherwise, changes 
;;         "It is certain" to "Outlook good",
;;         "Outlook is good" to "Ask again later",
;;         "Ask again later" to "Outlook not so good",
;;         and "Outlook not so good" to "It is certain".

(define (magic-8-ball s)
  (local 
    [
     ;; new-list represents the new value of the list 8-ball-answers
     ;;          after every time the function is called.
     (define next-answer (first 8-ball-answers))]
    (begin
      (cond [(equal? s "") no-answer]
            [else (set! 8-ball-answers (append (rest 8-ball-answers)
                                               (list next-answer)))])
      next-answer)))
```

Here is my test case:

```
(check-expect (and (equal? (magic-8-ball "Do you love me?")
                       "It is certain")
               (equal? (magic-8-ball "How is your life?")
                       "Outlook good")
               (equal? (magic-8-ball "") 
                       "you did not ask a question, try again")
               (equal? (magic-8-ball "2nd0A-wmQ232.asdA?") 
                       "Ask again later")
               (equal? (magic-8-ball "No questions here")
                       "Outlook not so good")
               (equal? (magic-8-ball "Now do you hate me?")
                       "It is certain"))
               true))
```

The test should pass, but mine did not. The problem occurs when the string is empty.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?
Thanks!

Comment: Possibly, but first: can you tell us what it is you're trying to do? I imagine you'd want to start something like this:  "I'm working on a homework assignment where we're trying to model a magic 8 ball. The assignment requires (etc, etc.) I've written this test case, but it produces *this*, when I expect it to produce *this*."

Comment: Echoing John's comment and adding: I would suggest breaking up the tests into six separate ones which can individually pass or fail, rather than one giant one which won't tell you much if any one of the conditions fails.

Comment: Please fix your question. As of now, `no-answer` is not defined. Also, `(empty? "")` does not return `#t`, so you may want to use a `string-empty?`, which can be written using `string-length` if it doesn't exist. My guess is that the empty test is the crux of your problems, but I cannot be sure with the information as written.

Comment: Including a contract and purpose would help us figure out what the desired behavior is.

Answer (score 1):

Good, you fixed your empty check. Now I can run the code :)

The empty check was not your only problem. Look at the following block of code and tell me what you expect:

```
(begin
  (cond [(equal? s "") no-answer]
        [else (set! 8-ball-answers (append (rest 8-ball-answers)
                                           (list next-answer)))])
  next-answer)
```

I expect `next-answer`, independent of the condition results. I imagine that you probably wanted your `else` condition to return `next-answer` after cycling the answers. The problem is your `begin`. You test a condition, then return `next-answer`. Perhaps you wanted something like:

```
(cond [(equal? s "") no-answer]
      [else (begin (set! 8-ball-answers (append (rest 8-ball-answers)
                                                (list next-answer)))
                   next-answer)])
```

This returns `no-answer` if the string is empty and the cycled `next-answer` otherwise. While probably correct, I think this code is rather ugly. Consider refactoring the cycle-and-return-next-answer bit. The structure is nasty as I have it.